# Adding a list of sin waves such that they run for one period and moves on to the next sin wave with a different phase/amplitude

Tags: trigonometry, continuity, graphing-functions

I have a list of sin waves
$$[A_1\sin⁡(x+P_1 ),A_2\sin⁡(x+P_2 )…A_n\sin⁡(x+P_n ) ]$$
and I want have them be graphed in such a way that there is no discontinuity between them. my current method is to simply limit each wave between $0$ and $2\pi$ and shift each consecutive wave $2\pi$ to the right.
$$[A_1\sin(x+P_1)\{0<x<2\pi\},A_2\sin(x+P_2)\{2\pi<x<4\pi\}...A_n\sin(x+P_n)\{2\pi(n-1)<x<2\pi n\}]$$ This results in discontinuities in the Graph [image: graph]. What I want to achieve is a graph of these sin waves have no discontinuities in their graph and have them graphed in a singular function rather than a list of functions that get moved to the right. I know that summing up sin waves won't result in what I want to achieve and will simply sum peaks and valleys. So using a summation won't work $\sum_{i=1}^nA_n\sin(x+P_n)$. For more details I am using the graphing calculator Desmos which has some annoying limitations but I should be able to work around them if any problem does come up. Another parameter I would like to achieve is to have the first derivative must be continuous to achieve a "smooth" function. So it should achieve G1 continuity as well. Any approximation is also wonderful. Here is a crude drawing of roughly what I would like to end up with, I know it might not be completely perfect but a rough approximation of the amplitudes and phase-shifts would be perfect. [image: 2]

For reference I'm trying to graphically simulate quadrature amplitude modulation. From a [different StackExchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/84919/how-are-discontinuities-in-quadrature-modulated-signal-qam-physically-produced) forum I know in reality it's done with digital to analogue conversion but I know that can't be easily replicated using mathematical functions at least to my knowledge and few hours of searching google for a mathematical representation of DAC.

Solved:

Smooth step function:

$$S(x)={\begin{cases}0,&x\leq 0\\3x^{2}-2x^{3},&0\leq x\leq 1\\1,&1\leq x\\\end{cases}} $$

Applying the smooth step function:

$$A_{mplitude}(x)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}{((A_{i+1}-A_{i}) S(x-2\pi i+0.5)+A_{i})}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-2}{A_{i+1}}}$$

$$P_{hase}(x)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}{((P_{i+1}-P_{i}) S(x-2\pi i+0.5)+P_{i})}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-2}{P_{i+1}}}$$

Apply the function to a sin wave:

$$A_{mplitude}(x)\sin{(x-P_{hase}(x))}$$

Before solution:

[image]

After solution:

[image]

And the first derivative to show that it has first derivative continuity:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a continuous function $f(x)$ that is equal to $A_1\sin⁡(x+P_1)$ over one interval of values of $x$ and is equal to $A_2\sin⁡(x+P_2)$ over another interval of values--kind of like the graph you showed, but without the vertical "jumps" from one part of the function to another. This essentially forces something much like what you have, except that you might choose different endpoints for your intervals, not just multiples of $2\pi$. If that's not what you mean, please edit the question.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean! But choosing different endpoints that vary depending on the corresponding will lead to another problem that I just realized is that I also need the first derivative to be continues otherwise it will not be a "smooth" function.

Comment: Requiring that $f$ be smooth imposes an additional constraint, which means this generally cannot be done. In particular, continuity at $x=a$ would require $A_1 \sin(a+P_1) = A_2 \sin(a+P_2)$ and smoothness at $x=a$ would require $A_1 \cos(a+P_1) = A_2 \cos(a+P_2)$. Adding the requirements in quadrature shows that $A_1^2=A_2^2$, which may not be true.

Comment: If we disregard the need for continuity is there a possible way to turn just the list of sin waves into a singular function rather than a list of functions.

Comment: Mathematically, what you have is **already** a single function and not a "list" of functions. Your single function is merely specified piecewise. You can change the syntax of how this is done so that the function is defined by something that looks more like what you might think of as a single formula (joined by $+$ operations), but unless you have a really good notation for indicator functions this tends to make the function much more complicated, not less, and even with indicator functions I don't see how it's really an improvement.

Comment: I completely forgot about piecewise functions and it seems to work and behave just like one thank you! I'm going to keep mucking around to see if I can figure out how to make the function smooth but for now i'll take your word for it that it can't be done in the scenario I have because the amplitudes are completely random. Thank you so much for your help though.

Comment: @DarkLordOfPhysics Now it's not possible to accurately create the exact same function with G1 continuity but would it be possible to compute a Fourier series to get "close enough" to the output as there are tolerances and it doesn't need to be perfect. Is there a good and easy way to compute the coefficients for a list of sin functions who run like the graph I have attached. And is it possible to do this iteratively for any list of functions with random amplitude and phase shift.

Comment: You've given an example graph of the list of various periods with discontinuous phase and ampliture at multiples of $2\pi$.  Could you give a sketch of what you *want* that graph to turn into?

Comment: I'll edit the post to show my goal with a crudely drawn MS paint drawing if that's ok!

Comment: I solved it. sadly the question got closed but you can use a smoothstep function for the amplitude and for the phase-shift and apply that function to a new sin wave and it just works and it's G(1) continuous aswell